# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver in vscode. have added referenced libraries jar file, error persists

Tags: java, mysql, visual-studio-code, jdbc, connection

Here is a little insight, I have reinstalled VS Code and its extensions, used this code without any extensions, and the error remains the same.

I also added the jar file in referenced libraries and refreshed it, but the code doesn't work.

I tried importing `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` and `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`, tried changing `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` to `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`.

This code works in eclipse IDE, but I would rather not switch my entire operation to eclipse.

```java
import java.sql.*;

public class newapp2jdbc {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sql_workbench";
    String uname = "root";
    String pass = "0768";
    String query = "select name from student where id=3";

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, uname, pass);
    Statement st = con.createStatement();

    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

    rs.next();
       
    String name = rs.getString(1);
    System.out.println(name);
    st.close();
    con.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes the problem is still there, but i started using eclipse so i dont have to face it right now

Answer (score 1):

First try to use the command **Java:Clean Language Server Workspace** in the command palette to see if the problem can be solved.

[image]

***If the problem persists, follow the steps below to create a new project.***

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to open the command palette, search for and select **Java:Create Java Project...**

   [image]
2. Then Select **No Build tools** --> select a folder --> type the project name ([Screenshot of steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8gP6.jpg))
3. Now that you have a new Java project, in the **JAVA PROJECTS** panel click the plus sign after `src` to create a new class

   [image]
4. Type the class name (`newapp2jdbc`) and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

   [image]
5. Paste the code from your question in the generated **newapp2jdbc.java** file
6. Click the plus sign to the right of `Referenced Libraries` to add dependencies

   [image]

   *Here is `mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar` for me, you can download it from the **MySQL** official website.*
7. The code can now be run.

   [image]

***Note: The full **[Extension Pack for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack)** needs to be installed***